# How to make a Parallel processing work in C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I have block of C++ code. First nested for loop calculate velocity of 'n' number of particle for numbers of iteration.i.e 2d array. This block take 3-4 sec to execute.
I have to use this velocity to calculate Energy in another nested for loop.But that block takes several weeks. I want to use MPI to make my execution faster and I have to collect all E[a][b] data and write in csv file.

```
for(int j=0:j<iterations;j++){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        v[i][j]=.....;
    }
}
```

Above code run in 3-4 sec.

```
for(int a=0;a<10000;a++){

    for(int b=0;b<250;b++){
    for(int j=0;j<iterations;j++){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    ....
    ....
    ....
    E[a][b]=v[i][j]*....;
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Above code take several weeks.

Comment: You can split this, outer, range: `for(int a=0;a<10000;a++)` into as many threads as you have spare.

Comment: Note that you might be compounding your problem with cache misses due to the access pattern of `v[i][j]`. That won't be helping performance at all.

Comment: TL;DR swap for `for(i...)` and `for(j...)` loops